# How to set object in state arrays from dynamic form in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, state

I am building a react app. I have created a dynamic form (generates X number of input fields (1-10) based on the number chosen by the user).That part works perfectly. However, I am wanting to add a second input field inside my mapping function. For context, I am building a flash card app. I want to add the term and the definition to the same state item. The idea is that each state array will hold an object for the term and an object for the definition in order to keep each definition with its proper term. Notice that the state items are named after the index of my mapping function. So for example, I want to send the term and definition to this.state.0 for the first term, etc... for each term and definition depending on how many the user wants to add (up to 10). Right now I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'term' of undefined
```

So how do I set each term and its definition to the state array, each to their own object of the array? Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class TermForm extends Component {
    state = {
        0: [],
        1: [],
        2: [],
        3: [],
        4: [],
        5: [],
        6: [],
        7: [],
        8: [],
        9: []
    }

    onChange = (event) => this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.numberOfTerms);
        return (
            this.props.numberOfTerms.map((i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <input type="text" name={i.term} placeholder="TERM" value={this.state.i.term} onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                    <input type="text" name={i.def} placeholder="TERM" value={this.state.i.def} onChange={this.onChange}></input>
                </div>
            ))
        )
    }
}

export default TermForm
```

Any ideas about how I could set the object of a state array through my mapping function? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: For clarification, could you give an example of such a state?

Comment: Plus what is the "numberOfTerms" in props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'term' of undefined` coz there is no such field on that location

```
value={this.state.i.term}
```

As per your initial state, it should look like this :

```
value={this.state.i[0]?.term}
```

The same change will be applicable for your `def` field also

---

Suggestion :

You should change the state something like this :

```
state = [
    {
        term : "" ,
        def : ""
    },
    {
        term : "" ,
        def : ""
    },
    ...
]
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
value={this.state[i].term}
```